# How to write Firebase database rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want in my Firebase database to accept values only one time. And then once anyone has submitted anything to database, they won't be able to enter any data again until they delete their earlier values.

How to implement this `".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"`
in a way that meets our requirements?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to this problem:

1. Each user needs to have their own data
2. A user can only write if "their own data" doesn't exist yet
3. A user can delete "their own data"

The first step of associating a user with their own data is easiest by storing each user's data in its own node that is identified by the user's UID. E.g. if your UID is `abi5586378` and mine is `puf209103`, we'd have our data like this:

```
"userData": {
  "abi5586378": {
    "name": "Abhishek Singh"
  }
  "puf209103": {
    "name": "Frank van Puffelen"
  }
}
```

To secure this, we can use these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "userDara": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "
          auth.uid === $uid && /* user can only write their own data */
          (
            !data.exists() || /* user can write if there is no data yet */
            !newData.exists() /* user can clear existing data */
          )
        "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank. This looks like a good answer to an unclear question. Since you seem to have a handle on what the OP is answering, are you able to edit it, so as to make it clearer to a wider audience? I don't know how useful it is at present for anyone other than the question author.